# Azure Table Storage batch inserts across multiple partitions?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

The following method can be used to batch insert a collection of entities as a single transaction:

```
CloudTable.ExecuteBatch(TableBatchOperation batch)
```

If any of the entities fail during insert, then nothing will be inserted from the collection.  This is only available when inserting into one partition.

**Is it possible to do something like this across multiple partitions?**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No. All entities in a batch must have the same PartitionKey. If your entities have different PartitionKeys, they need to be in separate batches. For more details about entity batch transactions, please see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd894038.aspx.